# Filling Cells from DataGridView of N size

Tags: arrays, vba, visual-studio, datagridview

I need help filling some cells with random 1s and 0s from a NxN Array.As you can see in the picture it doesn't fill the 4x4 array.[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/RpKXe.jpg)

```
Public Class Proyecto
  Dim columna, fila As Byte

  'Dim rnd As New Random
  Private Sub B_Ingresar_Click(sender As Object, e As EventArgs) Handles B_Ingresar.Click
    Dim i As Byte
    Dim r As Byte
    columna = Val(TB_TamX.Text)
    fila = Val(TB_TamY.Text)

    Me.DGV.ColumnCount = columna
    Me.DGV.RowCount = fila
    Me.DGV.RowHeadersWidth = 60

    For i = 0 To columna - 1
        Me.DGV.Columns(i).Width = 40
        Me.DGV.Columns(i).HeaderText = i + 1
        r = CInt((Rnd() * 1))
        DGV.Rows.Add(Str(r))
        'DGV.Columns.Add(Tostr(r))

    Next
    For i = 0 To fila - 1
        Me.DGV.Rows(i).HeaderCell.Value = (i + 1).ToString
        ' r = CInt((Rnd() * 1))
        ' DGV.Rows.Add(Str(r))
    Next
End Sub
```

Answer (score 0):

To keep things simple… loop through the columns and set the column headers. The first loop does this but also it is trying to add a row which is not needed. Take out the `DGV.Rows.Add` and random stuff as this loop simply adds the column header text. Do the same with the rows as the next for loop does to set the row header text. What is missing is a double loop to go through the rows and columns and set each cell a random Boolean value. Hope that makes sense.

```
For i = 0 To fila - 1
  Dim curRow = DGV.Rows(i)
  For j = 0 To columna - 1
    r = CInt((Rnd() * 1))
    curRow.Cells(j).Value = r.ToString()
  Next
Next
```

Comment: Thank you,it worked perfectly. I really appreciate your help